# How do I format a date as ISO date(mongodb) using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs, isodate, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert below-mentioned date to ISO format(MongoDB)

```
  var d = { storedDate: '26/06/2020 05:55:29 PM' };
```

I'm however unable to find the parameter that I need to use to get it in the format which I want. I tried the below piece of code.

moment(d.storedDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");

How can I get it as `ISODate("2020-06-26T17:55:29.274Z")`

Please advice

Comment: `moment().toISOString()` [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze getting like this 2020-06-26T00:11:35.000Z if i use moment(d.storedDate).toISOString()

Answer (score 0):

`moment(d.storedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toISOString()`  will return ISO date only in UTC that you need for MongoDb. You need to provide the input date format as well.

Comment: getting like this 2020-06-26T09:55:29.000Z

Comment: ISODate() format is just for the representation purpose, it's wrapper around Date(). Internally MongoDB stores date in integer or string format. 
You can use ISODate() helper method here.  Check these links : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/ ,
https://www.compose.com/articles/understanding-dates-in-compose-mongodb/#:~:text=ISODate()

Comment: please help me out .what should i do here

Comment: Try this : var date = moment(d.storedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate();
 var output = new ISODate(date);

Comment: @martinkumar You are doing this on client side code or server side code? Can you explain more.

Comment: doing in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store proper `Date` object, use

```
moment(d.storedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate()
```

You should not store date/time values as strings, use proper data type.

Comment: getting below error moment(...).getDate is not a function

Comment: Sorry, should be toDate()

Comment: Then provide the format of input data, see my update.

Comment: i see following output 2020-06-26T09:55:29.000Z but my expectation "ISODate("2020-06-26T17:55:29.274Z")"

Comment: I think that is just the way how your client **display** it. Should be a proper Date object.